# Referenced assembly targets a different processor than the application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Using VS 2010 Express.
This question has been asked before, in this post: [How to solve warning "Referenced assembly targets a different processor than the application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244464/how-to-solve-warning-referenced-assembly-targets-a-different-processor-than-the)

But when I go to my project properties I don't have a compile tab. The Build tab lists a platform combo box, but I only have one option to choose from which is 'Active(Any CPU'.

Maybe this is due to me using the express version.  How else can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Most likely you have a 64-bit machine, compile the program for AnyCPU, and when running it it will run as a 64-bit process, but then you're referencing a 32-bit (x86) assembly. Try using that combo to add x86 as a build target and make that active.

Comment: I am using a 32 bit machine.  I should have put that in my post, sorry.

Comment: Then it's the opposite, the referenced assembly/ies is 64-bit (x64).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a new configuration.

To do this, use the solution-level combo box on the main toolbar, and select Configuration Manager.

Under the 'Active Solution Platform' combo box, choose < New >.